# How to turn a curl into elasticsearch-py query format?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

How to write elasticsearch-py query to query the same data as below?

```
--data-binary '{"query": {"filtered": {"query": {"bool": {"should":[ {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"aaa\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"bbb\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"ccc\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, } }, "filter": {"bool": {"must":[ {"range": {"@timestamp": {"from":111,"to":222}}}, {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query":"file:(\"ddd")"}}, "_cache":true}}]}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is working in curl, the following works with the same query.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT = "url_to_your_elasticsearch_node"
es = Elasticsearch([ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT])


request= '{"query": {"filtered": {"query": {"bool": {"should":[ {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"aaa\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"bbb\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, {"query_string": {"query":"request.action.raw:\"ccc\" AND (loglevel:INFO)"}}, } }, "filter": {"bool": {"must":[ {"range": {"@timestamp": {"from":111,"to":222}}}, {"fquery": {"query": {"query_string": {"query":"file:(\"ddd")"}}, "_cache":true}}]}}}}}' 
results = es.search(index="index_name", doc_type="doctype_name", body=request)
```

Notice that, besides the request, you need to configure the following parameters in the script:

- **ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT** : URL of your elasticsearch node or cluster
- **index_name**: the index name.
- **doc_type**: the doctype name.