# How to make urlib return an array in python - Parse the results of a call to elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, urllib2, aggregation

For example, I would like to aggregate by state, but the following returns data tyep is string not an array . 
How can I write an Elasticsearch terms aggregation that return an array ?

part of my code:

```
import urllib2 as urllib
import json
query = {
    "size":0,
  "aggs":{
     "states":{
        "terms":{
           "field":"states.raw",
            "size":8
        }
     }
  }

}

query = json.dumps(query )
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, query , headers)
out = urllib2.urlopen(req)
rs = out.read()

print type(rs )
```

return :

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "states": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "New York",
               "doc_count": 200
            },
            {
               "key": "California",
               "doc_count": 10
            },
            {
               "key": "New Jersey",
               "doc_count": 10
            },
            {
               "key": "North Carolina",
               "doc_count": 1802
            },
            {
               "key": "North Dakota",
               "doc_count": 125
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I try to get return data by rs['aggregations']['states']['buckets'][0]['key']
but get the error msg

```
"TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"
```

I found the return data type is string ,how to make the return data is an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
import json 
... 
rs = json.loads(rs)
```

Then rs will become an object that you access using `s['aggregations']['states']['buckets'][0]['key']`

However, it's recommended that you use the python client for elasticsearch instead of writing your own, as the latter already handles what you are looking for among other things. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609819/how-to-turn-a-curl-into-elasticsearch-py-query-format/45610273#45610273111) for an example on how to run a query using elasticsearch-py.

Here's the link for elasticsearch-py's documentation:

- https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/